# Where can I listen to the song bramble blast from little big planet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I've search for the song everywhere throughout the web but it wasn't found because it doesn't seem to exist.

Anybody know where I can find it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a song somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no song by that name in the LBP2 soundtrack, as far as I'm aware.

*Bramble Blast* is from Donkey Kong Country 2, not Little Big Planet.  It was also reprised in Super Smash Brothers Brawl.